# How to manage migrations with gino in python

Tags: python, sanic

I'm trying to use [gino](http://gino.fantix.pro/en/latest/) with [sanic](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for an experimental project. And I blocked with migrating my model.py to the database.

I used `flask-migrate` when I use flask and sqlalchemy (more exactly, it's flask-sqlalchemy though)

What is the common tool for managing db migration in sanic & gino stack?

Comment: [Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) may be not a part of sanic\gino stack, but it's based on sqlalchemy and should work fine with the sqlalchemy-based gino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this issue: https://github.com/fantix/gino/issues/374

And these instructions: https://gist.github.com/omarryhan/cb7bf6d7142c154496ba6623a56326c2#file-sanic-gino-alembic-migrations-setup